# Copy list of files recursively using Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a list of files in a text file.

Example, content of `t.txt` file:

```
a.txt
b.jpg
c.bat
```

I want a script to copy files from a source directory, and its subdirectories, to a particular destination.

As of now, I am using the following within the Command Prompt (CMD):

```bash
for /f %I in (t.txt) do copy "C:\ProgramFiles\"%I . /y
```

This copies files only from `ProgramFiles` directory to the present destination.

How can I modify this, to allow the search of its subdirectories too?

Comment: How do you want to handle duplicate file names? Say `a.txt` is found in both `C:\ProgramFiles\foo` and `C:\ProgramFiles\bar` - which one should be copied to the destination?

Comment: You should start by correcting your syntax, i.e. `"C:\ProgramFiles\"%I` should be `"C:\ProgramFiles\%I"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily do that via `xcopy` in windows(cmd), something like this :

```
@echo off
set "src=H:\JP and Stella\Part 1\Style\Logo\Free dom"
set "dest=C:\Users\starz\Downloads\Selected Photos\"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("t.txt") do (
    for /r "%src%" %%J in ("*%%I") do (
        xcopy /y "%%J" "%dest%"
    )
)
```

in my code, it will read the file names from `t.txt`, search for them in the `H:\JP and Stella\Part 1\Style\Logo\Free dom` directory and its subdirectories, and copy them to the `C:\Users\starz\Downloads\Selected Photos\` directory

is it ok ?

Comment: It didnt work!!! Am I doing something wrong?

for /f "usebackq delims=" %I in ("t.txt") do xcopy /s /y "H:\%I" "C:\Users\starz\Downloads\Selected Photos"

It didnt search into the subdirectories... It just searches in the H: directory

Comment: Still looking into the present directory only:

C:\Users\starz\Downloads\Selected Photos>xcopy /s /y "H:\_KAR4697.jpg" "C:\Users\starz\Downloads\Selected Photos\"
File not found - _KAR4697.jpg
0 File(s) copied

Comment: Found out that if i remove %I, it is looking for directories and subdirectories but i use %I, it is not looking inside the directories.. i think it should be rewritten in some other way..

Comment: The code works for all jpg files but i am looking for a list of jpg files. Eg; t.txt containing a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg. The code should get the file from folder and its subfolders..

Comment: I have a sample file say: t.txt containing the following content:

STZ_1.jpg
STZ_2.jpg

This file is present in H: directory under H:\JP and Stella\Part 1\Style\Logo\Free dom path.

The code should ideally look for all directories and subdirectories and find the file and copy it to a destination folder specified..

If it is complex, just naming the full structure or path of the file also will be helpful to me.... Example : H:\JP and Stella\Part 1\Style\Logo\Free dom\STZ_1.jpg